# Conditional url with ternary operator in anchor tag href throws Parse Error Angular

Tags: angular, href, conditional-operator

Good day developers. I´m trying to set dynamically a URL for my anchor tag href in a html template but I´m receiving this error:

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 30 in 
[somevariable?['/somelink/{{ some.id }}?someparam={{ paramid }}&origin=origin']:'']
```

the href would be redirecting to an URL if some random variable of boolean type has a true value, thus:

```
 <a [href]="(somevariable)?('/somelink/{{ some.id }}?someparam={{ paramid }}&origin=origin'):''">
 </a>
```

is there a better approach for this?...thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly answering your question but you should use `routerLink` instead of `href` if that link is a route on your app.

Comment: even using routerLink the error persists. Really thanks for your comment @Frank Fajardo

Comment: Try this: `"{{ somevariable ? '/somelink/' + some.id + '?someparam=' + paramid + '&origin=origin' : '' }}"`. But your anchor tag could end up without an actual link, so maybe you should be using `*ngIf` instead of conditionally changing the link on your anchor tag.

Comment: perfect Fank Fajardo...would be nice you to answer this properly outside the comments....Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your interpolation to this:

```
<a href="{{ somevariable ? '/somelink/' + some.id + '?someparam=' + paramid + '&origin=origin' : '' }}">
```

But your anchor tag could end up without a link if `somevariable` is false. So I would suggest you instead hide the anchor tag in that instance using `*ngIf`:

```
<a *ngIf="somevariable" href="{{ '/somelink/' + some.id + '?someparam=' + paramid + '&origin=origin' }}">
```

Additionally, I would suggest you use `routerLink` instead `href` if `/somelink/...` is a route in your app so your app does not reload when the user follows (clicks on) the link.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Router.navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) And [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

In .ts file

```
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

 navigate() {
    const someId = 1;
    if (someVariable) {
      let navigationExtra: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams: { someParam: 'x', origin: 'origin' },
        fragment: 'anchor',
      };

      this.router.navigate([`/somelink/${someId}`], navigationExtra);
    }
  }
```

In template:

```
<a (click)="navigate()">Go to ...</a>
```